# Static TableViewCells Adjust Height, Fill View Height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

My app requires a few things that UITableViews make a lot simpler to do. I'm running into this issue though: I want the bottom cell to always be at the bottom of the view controller, and I want all the cells to dynamically adjust their height so every single cell fits inside of the viewcontroller, no scrolling needed to see more cells.

Essentially I want 3 or 4 big tableViewCells that all dynamically change height depending on which device is being used. Caveat: all these cells need to be different heights. Any ideas?

Comment: I would use -tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: and view.frame.size.height to calculate the height for each cell. You can indeed have dynamic height for your cells. You could always use % logic to calculate the height. For example cell1 25% of view cell2 50% cell3 10% and cell4 15% of the frame's height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @Vig's comment:

You didn't specify how the cell heights were being determined, so I assumed they weren't normalised between 0 and 1.

Therefore, in your `UITableViewController` you need the following variables:

For my example I'm using `absoluteCellHeights` as the data to determine the cell heights, this would need to change for your purposes.

```
var absoluteCellHeights: [CGFloat] = [50, 40, 20, 10] {
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

`normalisedCellHeights` takes the `absoluteCellHeights` and scales them to be in the interval 0 to 1. However, in the case `absoluteCellHeights` is just full of zeros nil will be returned.

```
var normalisedCellHeights: [CGFloat]? {
    let totalHeight = absoluteCellHeights.reduce(0, combine: +)
    let normalisedHeights: [CGFloat]? = totalHeight <= 0 ? nil : absoluteCellHeights.map { $0 / totalHeight }

    return normalisedHeights
}
```

Now in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` you can do:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    //  Swift 1.2, which is why I'm using 'let' here.
    let height: CGFloat

    //  It is assumed there is only one section.
    if let normalisedHeight = self.normalisedCellHeights?[indexPath.row] {
        height = normalisedHeight * tableView.frame.height
    } else {
        height = 50.0 // Just a random value.
    }

    return height
}
```

Finally, because you don't want the table to scroll you need to add `tableView.scrollEnabled = false` when you're configuring your table view. Possibly IB if you're using Storyboards?

The final result:

[image]

Comment: awesome in depth explanation. Thanks for the help

Comment: I just updated my answer a bit to include the event that `absoluteCellHeights` may just contain zeros. But cheers! I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Superb explanation and answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can override `UITableViewDelegate` method and return a custom height for each cell based on `indexPath`

```
-       (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
   heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

In this delegate method, just return the height of your UITableView divided by the number of rows in your UITableView.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return tableView.frame.size.height / tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0)
}
```

(0) assumes you have only one section in your table view.

Comment: But different depending on device, unless you expect each of the 3 to 4 cells to have potentially unique heights.